# How do I grep for a word and then uncomment that line only if its commented

Tags: bash, unix, grep

Writing a bash script where I have to `grep` for `property1` in another file called `filename.conf` and check if that `property1`already exists. In a case where there is already `property1=correctvalue` in the filename.conf, I will first want to check whether there is commented or uncommented property1 using grep -q. If its present but its not equal to `correctvalue` then change it to `correctvalue` and uncomment if commented.

Else, if the property1 doesn't exist, then write `property1=correctvalue`.

Example:
Sample input 1

```
property1 = correctvalue
```

Sample output 1  (where you do nothing)

```
property1 = correctvalue
```

Sample input 2

```
property1=correctvalue
```

Sample output 2 (where you do nothing)

```
property1=correctvalue
```

Sample input 3

```
property1= incorrectvalue
```

Sample output 3

```
property1=correctvalue
```

Sample input 4

```
#property1=correctvalue
```

Sample output 4 (uncommented it)

```
property1=correctvalue
```

Sample input 5

```
#property1=incorrectvalue
```

Sample output 5  (uncomment it and change to correctedvalue)

```
property1=correctvalue
```

This is what I have so far:

```
if grep -q '^property1' filename.conf; then #How do I write it so it will grep for either "#property1" or "property1"?
    #if the content after "=" is not "correctvalue" ignoring the space before/after "=", then correct it
    #if there is "#" in the beginning then remove the "#"
else
    echo "property1=correctvalue" 
fi
```

Comment: I suggest to take a look at `sed`.

Comment: @Cyrus  I'm very new to bash scripting, can you show me how its done?

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: @Cyrus I did include the sample input! Its right under "Example".

Comment: @Cyrus added sample inputs and outputs! hope that helps!

Comment: `How do I write it so it will grep for either "#property1" or "property1"?` Please learn regex. That's exactly what regex is for.

Comment: @asfas - The `property1=` can't occur more than once, can it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like just:

```
sed 's/#\?property1 *=.*/property1=correctvalue/'
```

tested with:

```
$ for i in 'property1 = correctvalue' 'property1=correctvalue' 'property1= incorrectvalue' '#property1=correctvalue' '#property1=incorrectvalue '; do echo "$i|$(sed 's/#\?property1 *=.*/property1=correctvalue/' <<<"$i")"; done | column -t -s '|' -N input,output
input                       output
property1 = correctvalue    property1=correctvalue
property1=correctvalue      property1=correctvalue
property1= incorrectvalue   property1=correctvalue
#property1=correctvalue     property1=correctvalue
#property1=incorrectvalue   property1=correctvalue
```

You can learn regexes with fun with regex crosswords online.

> How do I write it so it will grep for either "#property1" or "property1"?

```
grep '^#\?property1'
grep -E '^#?property1'
grep '^\(#property1\|property1\)'
grep -E '^(#property1|property1)'
```

Comment: Sorry I'm still confused. What about the case where there is `##property1=correctvalue` then? Can you explain what every part of that `sed` does? so I can just use sed instead of grep?

Comment: `What about the case where there` Change the regex appropriately to match such case. `Can you explain what every part` [Here is a great sed introduction](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html), but 99% of sed is used it's only `s` command anyway. I'm sure there are many more good sed tutorials on the net. Also, as mentioned, regex crosswords are a great and easy place to learn regex. `so I can just use sed instead of grep?` sed is stream __editor__, grep is lines __filter__. You seem to want to edit the line, so use sed. grep is for filtering, not editing.

Comment: Can you show me how to edit it for `##property=correctvalue` please? And the sed wouldn't add the `property1=correctvalue` if its missing from the file, right? so how would I add that?

Comment: Can you please edit your answer accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to *learn regex* fully for this rather simple task; a lesson about a [*quantifier*](https://regexone.com/lesson/kleene_operators) for the optional space before the equal sign and about [`.`, `^`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/BRE-syntax.html) and [`\<`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/regexp-extensions.html) to match respectively any character, the beginning of the line and the property,  is enough. But it's certainly good advice to *look at `sed`*.

You need not bother with recognizing the different cases of commentation and value correctness - you can simply replace a line with the property assignment by the desired output in any case, and only if none found append it at the end.

```
sed -i '1{x;s/^/property1=correctvalue/;x;};/\<property1 *=/{s/.*//;x;};$G;$s/\n$//' filename.conf
```

This first puts `property1=correctvalue` into the *hold space*, then looks for the `property1` line where it's replaced by the correct value and the hold space is erased, and lastly appends the correct value if it's still on hold.